# minimum, maximum of bits required to store n integer

Tags: python

my teacher did an example where he showed us some sample output and i was trying to figure out how he got the numbers. here's his sample output

```
          unsigned     max value  max value
number     b bits      b-1 bits   b bits
     2       2           1           3
    10       4           7          15
    20       5          15          31
   100       7          63         127
  1000      10         511        1023
999999      20      524287     1048575
```

he said he found 
the the minimum number of bits b required to store n as an unsigned integer
• the maximum unsigned integer that can be stored using b − 1 bits
• the maximum unsigned integer that can be stored using b bits

is there a formula to do this because i cant seem to recognize the pattern

Comment: Call the value in the 2nd column `n`.  Then the value in the 3rd column is `2**(n-1)-1`, and the value in the 4th column is `2**n-1`.  The answers you got explain everything else.

Comment: thanks, how exactly do you get the value in the 2nd column?

Comment: You express the decimal value in binary, and count the number of bits.  @falsetru's answer shows several easy ways to do that using Python.  For example, what about 5?  In binary, that's 101.  So it requires 3 bits.

Answer (score 3):

Using [`int.bit_length()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#int.bit_length):

```
>>> (999999).bit_length()
20
>>> b = (999999).bit_length()
>>> 1 << b
1048576
>>> (1 << b) - 1
1048575
```

or using log<sub>2</sub>:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.ceil(math.log(999999, 2))
20.0
```

or using binary representation:

```
>>> format(999999, 'b')
'11110100001000111111'
>>> len(format(999999, 'b'))
20
>>> int('1' * 20, 2)
1048575

>>> bin(999999)
'0b11110100001000111111'
>>> len(bin(999999)) - 2
20
```

Answer (score 2):

In `n` bits, you can store a number up `(2^n)-1`<sup>1</sup>.  It's binary numbers.  If you're in a base-2 number system, then you can represent the number 8 as:

```
100 # 1*2^3 + 0*2^2 + 0*2^1
```

Or the number `12` as:

```
110 # 1*2^3 + 1*2^2 + 0*2^1
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>For the record, here I'm using the vernacular `^` as exponentiation.  Python actually uses a different operator (`**`).  (`^` is xor presumably borrowed from C).</sup>

Comment: Better to use `**` for exponentiation in a Python answer - `^` is bitwise xor.

Comment: Fair point -- however, even though the question is tagged python, it's really not python specific, so I'd rather use a more "vernacular" operator.  But, your point is well taken, so I've added a footnote.

Answer (score 0):

This outputs what you were showed in class:

```
import math

def calcNumbers(num):
    result = []
    b = int(math.ceil(math.log(num + 1, 2)))
    result.append(num)
    result.append(b)
    result.append(2**(b-1)-1)    # a**b is the same as a^b
    result.append(2**b-1)
    return tuple(result)

nums = [2, 10, 20, 100, 1000, 999999]

print '       |Unsigned|Max Value|Max Value'
print 'Number | b bits | b-1 bits| b bits'

for num in nums:
    print '% 7d|% 8d|% 8d |% 8d' % calcNumbers(num)

 # output
 #          |Unsigned|Max Value|Max Value
 #   Number | b bits | b-1 bits| b bits
 #         2|       2|       1 |       3
 #        10|       4|       7 |      15
 #        20|       5|      15 |      31
 #       100|       7|      63 |     127
 #      1000|      10|     511 |    1023
 #    999999|      20|  524287 | 1048575
```